# Unittest failed with sys.exit

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm trying to run my tests with unittest. Here is my structure :

```
projectname/
    projectname/
        foo.py
        bar.py
    tests/
        test_foo.py
        test_bar.py
```

I run it with :

```
cd tests/
python -m unittest discover
```

But in one file, for example **foo.py**, I use a `sys.exit(0)`, and unittest doesn't really like it :

```
$ python -m unittest discover
....E.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_foo (...)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
File "/home/.../projectname/foo.py", line 12, in write
    sys.exit(0)
SystemExit: 0

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.018s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

The `sys.exit()` use is voluntary, I can't remove it. I know there is an option called `exit` for the unittest.main function :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(exit=False)
```

But I want to test all the files in the *tests* directory. Another way is to do :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('.')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(tests)
```

It finds all the *test_* files, but the `sys.exit()` makes unittest crash.

Comment: Anything calling `sys.exit` is not a reusable unit due to its absolute nature, so unit testing isn't really applicable. However, you might be able to replace `sys.exit` for that piece of code, although that will also change the behaviour of the testee. You might be able to catch the exception it raises, you'd only have to catch `ExceptionBase`, I believe.

Answer (score 7):

`sys.exit` doesn't actually exit the interpreter. It just raise `SystemExit`. If that exception makes it to the top of the stack then the interpreter starts the process of exiting (with the relevant exit value).

`unittest` is unhappy as it is catching that `SystemExit` exception (so the interpreter won't actually exit), but the test is not described as expecting to raise that exception.

Try the following.

```
def test_exit_func(self):
    with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
        sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using sys.exit() in a module is a good idea. But if you must, what you should do is write a test case that wraps the module as a subprocess, probably using the subprocess module, and verity the exit code.  You'll probably also need a wrapper script to call.  In other words, you call an external Python script that imports that module, then it exits. The unittest framework can then report pass/fail by checking the return value of the subprocess.